# Is there any way to use jQuery like Ruby in IRB mode?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firebug

I love using irb to quickly check how my ruby code reacts. Im wondering is there a way to do the same say in Firebug or soem other tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, start up Firebug while using any page that has jquery loaded and type commands into the console.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I missed the console option. Im using a japanese version of firefox and so everything is in japanese. I just noticed the console option now.

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for irb and jquery. Much better would have been injecting jquery firebug.

Found this

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet

and it answers my question. If any one has any other tips please share.

Comment: This has been updated: [Updated jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet/)